# Valid Parentheses Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid

Tags: c++

I am getting Runtime error for this test case "(){}}{"

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address (pc 0x00000034481b bp 0x7ffd39b417d0 sp 0x7ffd39b41680 T0)
==30==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==30==Hint: this fault was caused by a dereference of a high value address (see register values below).  Dissassemble the provided pc to learn which register was used.
    #3 0x7f977b2d60b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==30==ABORTING
```

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isValid(string s) {
        stack<char>st;
        if(s.size()==1){
            return false;
        }
        for(int i =0; i<s.size(); i++){
            if(st.empty() && s[i]=='(' || s[i]=='[' || s[i]=='{'){
                st.push(s[i]);
            }
            else if(!st.empty() && s[i]=='(' || s[i]=='[' || s[i]=='{'){
                st.push(s[i]);
            }
            else if(!st.empty() &&  s[i]==')' ||s[i]==']' || s[i]=='}'){
                if(s[i] == ')' && st.top()=='(' ){
                    st.pop();
                }
                else if(s[i]=='}' && st.top()=='{'){
                    st.pop();
                }
                else if(s[i]==']' && st.top()=='['){
                    st.pop();
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(st.empty() && s[i]==')'||s[i]==']' || s[i]=='}'){
                  return false;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!st.empty()){
            return false;
        }
       else{
           return true;
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you know something about the operator precedence?

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ shunting yard algorithm".

Answer (score 0):

This condition is wrong:

```
else if (!st.empty() && s[i] == ')' || s[i] == ']' || s[i] == '}') {
```

It checks `s[i] == ']' || s[i] == '}'` even if `st` *is* empty. If the condition then becomes `true`, it will access `st.top()` and it may `st.pop()` in the following block statement. Both leads to *undefined behavior*.

Suggested change:

```
else if (!st.empty() && (s[i] == ')' || s[i] == ']' || s[i] == '}')) {
//                      ^                                         ^
```

This makes sure that `!st.empty()` must be `true` for the whole condition to be `true`.

The same goes for all your checks where you have `&&` and followed by one or more `||` conditions.

All the `if`s you need to change are listed as warnings in this
[**demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/xTdf396qr) in which I've also added a debug printout which clearly shows that `st` is in fact empty when you use `st.top()`.

Comment: Thanks its  Working now

Comment: @MdTalha Glad to hear it! You're welcome!